# I converted a pre-trained inception v3 model to tensor-flow lite and imported it into android studio, but I get below error

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/33/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/png/711093505 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list {...}} }} to activity {com.example.imageclassification/com.example.imageclassification.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1001 mismatch the shape on axis 1

Comment: It seems as a classification example with a problem to the output shape. Either you upload your tflite file or the whole project for us to take a look. If you do not want check how you load the labels and your model outputs

Comment: I used your tflite file inside [Netron](https://netron.app/) to take a look. It seems that your input is --float32[1,299,299,3] and output is --float32[1,3]....So I think there is an error on the output. You receive error of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1001 mismatch the shape on axis 1...BUT I see your output is with 3 classes

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you very much I was able to look and fix the issue. But now I am having an another issue , when I run my model on notebook and test the model on sample images it is detecting perfectly where as in android the detection is not accurate. Can you please help me with this. I tried to go through your article  https://farmaker47.medium.com/impact-of-different-image-loading-and-resizing-libraries-in-tensorflow-inference-output-and-df3c96a41825   but some how I am not able to get the accuracy. Please help me. Thank you in advance.